# Remove hyperlink when browser window < 830px but leave text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a site I'm building that's responsive. When the browser is less than 830 I would like the ABOUT and PROJECTS Links to not link to their category page. I still want the sub menu links to work.

When the site is viewed on a smartphone or tablet I would like the user to be able to click the ABOUT tab to show the sub menu links. Right now when I click the ABOUT tab it slides open but then takes me to the ABOUT page because I clicked the link.

```
            $("#menu-menu-1 li").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings().find('ul.sub-menu').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast'); 

            });//.click
```

http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?page_id=2

I have no idea how to do this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This will help if your website is directly opened in mobile or resized in screen browser

```
var windowResize = function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 830) { // your width
  $("#ABOUT").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  }
};

$(document).ready(windowResize);
$(window).resize(windowResize);
```

**Remember jquery uses css selectors**

Here is what you want

**Example set 1**

create a `class="AboutLink"` in the `<a>` attribute as below and use following jquery (use this)

```
<li id="menu-item-277" class="about menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-277 depth">

    <a **class="AboutLink"** href="https://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?cat=1">About</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-274" class="what_we_do menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-274 depth"><a href="https://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?cat=29">What We Do</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-273" class="meet_the_crew menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-273 depth"><a href="https://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?cat=28">Meet the crew</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

var windowResize = function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 830) { // your width
  $(".AboutLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  }
};

$(document).ready(windowResize);
$(window).resize(windowResize);
```

**Example set 2**

Don't create any class or something directly use following jquery (but avoid this as it will also effect other `<a>` tags in `.about` parent `div`)

```
var windowResize = function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 830) { // your width
  $(".about a").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  }
};

$(document).ready(windowResize);
$(window).resize(windowResize);
```

**Explainition**

In first case you directly select your element you wish to change the src, thus only that element gets effected by changed through jquery, while in second case you select the parent div by .about and then its child  by '.about a', now this select other  tags as well and apply jquery effcets there also.

Now I guess you can understand if I do this (mixture of both things)

```
<li id="menu-item-277" class="about menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-277 depth">

    <a class="AboutLink" href="https://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?cat=1">About</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-274" class="what_we_do menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-274 depth"><a href="https://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?cat=29">What We Do</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-273" class="meet_the_crew menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-273 depth"><a href="https://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?cat=28">Meet the crew</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jquery

```
var windowResize = function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 830) { // your width
  $(".about .AboutLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  }
};

$(document).ready(windowResize);
$(window).resize(windowResize);
```

**Final Edit**

just add use this script (it selects the `first <a>` in the `li . about`)

```
var windowResize = function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 830) { // your width
  $("li.about a:first").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  }
};

$(document).ready(windowResize);
$(window).resize(windowResize);
```

for enabling href back on window resize to > 830px width

```
var windowResize = function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 830) { // your width
  $("li.about a:first").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  }
  else {
  $("li.about a:first").attr("href", "https://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?cat=1");
  }
};
```

Now this should help you.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz4tW/)**</kbd>

Now this should meet all your requirements, using `.preventDefault()` will prevent the default behaviour of the link on window width < 830px. Just use following script.

```
var windowResize = function () {
    $('li.about a').click(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() < 830) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
};

$(document).ready(windowResize);
$(window).resize(windowResize);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for ".about".  When I use ".about a" all the JavaScript links in the sub menu are also voided. How do I only disable the JavaScript for the link that drop downs the sub menus?

Comment: because may be .about  have its child as an anchor tag so it will follow your thing or give class="about" to the anchor tag, then it will work, idea is to change the src attribute of the selected tag.

Comment: Can you look at my code and help me? I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: yeah sure, paste you html of fiddle it!

Comment: Can you view the page source? or inspect the code with firebug or something like that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added an edit hope it helps you understand things, also try to read about css selector..:)

Comment: The problem is that I can't add the .AboutLink class to the href because I don't have the option to in wordpress. It allows me to add a class to the menu link Li but thats it. you know how to do this in wordpress please let me know.

Comment: Okay that worked but one more thing. When I full screen the browser the about sub menu will not drop down. I think the script is stopping it from working. Can we use a reset when greater than > 830?

Comment: I have added the else condition. I t should now serve your purpose.

Comment: So I'm going to be using this code for more than just the about link. Is there a way to remove or reset the code when its > 830? It would be nice for this code to work on all the links I create that have sub menus.

Comment: Any suggestions? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Gaurav we're so close! Please help me with this.

Comment: Try the recent edit and revert back if any issues..:)

Comment: That’s not working. I think there should be an easier way to do this. The code should be more cohesive and less redundant for each menu item. I should be able to give each link the same class and have the script work only when the browser is < 830.  I wish the code could be simplified and work exactly as it should. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 830) { // assuming you mean width
        $('#ABOUT').removeAttr('href');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      // This will execute whenever the window is resized
     if($(window).width()< 830 )
         $('#about').removeAttr('href');
});
```

Comment: on how many elements you have got this class "about" , try to give it a id and change